# React js - How to set display size of dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I want to set the display size of the dropdown to show only 5 values and then apply scroll in React js.

Ex.

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

This works with normal HTML format. I want it to work it with React js. So is it possible to achieve this?

```html
<select onfocus="this.size = 5;" onblur="this.size = 1" onchange="this.size=1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
onFocus={(e)=>{e.target.size = 5}}
```

the same for the others be sure that the first letter after `on` in an uppercase. But I think it would be better if you create a state like this

```
this.state = {
   size: 1
}
```

and then change the select tag to

```
<select size={this.state.size} onFocus={()=>{this.setState({size: 5})}} onBlur={()=>{this.setState({size: 1})}} onChange={(e)=>{e.target.blur()}}>
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnutek7x/2/)

Comment: This is not working properly. The size property shows five records by default. Also after on change it's showing all 10 for some values. check in https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @parth it's the same for your snippet because `onblur` doesn't work until you click outside of the select tag and so the focus doesn't work to because it's already focused. wait a little I will edit my answer

Comment: It seems to work now. your answer is correct. Can you also help with using it material design? It only opens like 40px. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hkf2wm

Comment: @parth sorry I don't know how. but I think you shouldn't use `size` with material design. use your own css style instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-bootstrap` and create scrollable dropdown by applying `fixed` height for the `.dropdown-menu` element and set `overflow-y: scroll;`

For example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './QuantityInput.css'

export default class ScrollableDrop extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DropdownButton
        bsStyle="default"
        bsSize="small"
        style={{ maxHeight: "28px" }}
        title={"Qty"}
        key={1}
        id="dropdown-size-small"
      >
        <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="3" active>
          Active Item
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
      </DropdownButton>
    )
  }
}
```

> QuantityInput.css

```
.dropdown-menu {
  height: 70px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**OR**

You might wanna implement custom dropdown which loads on scroll

[Implementing Infinite Scroll With React Js without any plugin](http://voidcanvas.com/implementing-infinite-scroll-with-react-js-without-plugin/)

Comment: I don't want to use any library. I just want to do this by simple drop-down.

Comment: @parth So simply you can follow the second link that I have provided.